# htaccess url control

Tags: .htaccess

To prevent access to files in ajax folder so that they cannot be called directly by calling them in browser url.

ex:-   www.mysite.com/ajax/comment.php?act=12210&id=203  like this.
comment.php is an ajax called file. it should not be called directly by users. but some malicious one's may try this.

Whenever ajax appears in the url i need to redirect the request to a certain file saying you are  not allowd to do this.  But when the request is made using ajax i need to serve that request. i have tried htaccess solutions to allow access to that file only from localhost. but that prevents even legitimate access to that file.i.e by a actual ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do without htaccess.If you want to have a check to see if the request  Ajax request or not you can use below code:

Best Way:

```
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
       header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit;

 }
```

with htaccess u can try :

In your folder /ajax/ place a .htaccess file with below rules:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ajax
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this help. This is sure a solution. but i have heard that this 'XMLHttpRequest' header can be spoofed and their are tools available that actually can send this header even when when the call has been made from non-ajax.

Comment: Of course, but it does not mean you can not try. It will keep people from snooping around, but it won't stop those that want to abuse your system. You would have to take more measures such as access keys that are automatically generated.